# subtract time now from gorm create at in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, time, timezone

I am trying to do find the time difference between time now from the created at column in the database

I return a row in the database, i have the `created_at` column with the following time format

```
{"id":1,"email":"fUPvyBA@FApYije.ru","timezone":"pacific time","created_at":"2022-01-23T02:45:01.241589Z","updated_at":"2022-01-23T02:46:01.241591Z"}
```

so `created_at` = `2022-01-23T02:45:01.241589Z`

and

`time.Now()` = `2022-01-24 03:24:56.215573343 +0000 UTC m=+1325.103447033`

I tested with the following

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func TestTime() {

    timestart := "2022-01-23T02:45:01.241589Z"
    timeend := time.Now()
    timediff := timeend.Sub(timestart)
    fmt.Println("time diff is: ", timediff.Seconds())
    
}

TestTime()
```

but i get the following errors

```
cannot use <string> as <time.Time> in argument to timeend.Sub
```

How do i subtract to get the difference between the time i stored in `created_at` column from the current time `time.Now()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you trying to use an string on a time.Time parameter

Try this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func TestTime() {
    layout := time.RFC3339 // "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    timestart, err := time.Parse(layout, "2022-01-23T02:45:01.241589Z")
    
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    timeend := time.Now()
    timediff := timeend.Sub(timestart)
    fmt.Println("time diff is:", ltimediff.Seconds())
    
}

TestTime()
```

Comment: what is the layout for? `layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-03:00"`?

Comment: Its the format of the date. You should to tell Go what is the exact format of the string

Comment: got it..thanks..was thinking the time format were different even with `time.Now()` and will be a problem..but the subtraction worked fine

Comment: one other off topic question, what format do you advice `timezone` column to be to store user's timezone preference? plan to use it to return the local time to users...in terms of best practice...like this row `{"id":1,"email":"fUPvyBA@FApYije.ru","timezone":"pacific time","created_at":"2022-01-23T02:45:01.241589Z","updated_at":"2022-01-23T02:46:01.241591Z"}
`

Comment: There is two options, store the offset as hour (03:00, 04:00)  or the timezone as text ("America/Sao_Paulo")

Comment: i prefer the text but where do i get the standard list of timezone format like this? `America/Sao_Paulo`? so i can reference for all available timezones

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones